# Setup GLEW + CodeBlocks

Tags: opengl, codeblocks, glew

I want to make GLEW work with CodeBlocks and have been trying to get
the first method presented on the [site](http://glew.sourceforge.net/install.html) to work.
This is the method to compile glew statically into the executable.
 But I haven't managed to get it right.
I'm on a PC, Windows 7, running the CodeBlocks 10.05.

This is what I've done so far:

- Downloaded GLEW 1.7.0
- Unziped to C:
- Created empty project in CodeBlocks
- Moved glew.h, wglew.h and glew.c into my project source directory
- Added all of the three files to the project
- Changed include path in glew.c for glew.h and wglew.h from

  ```
  #include <GL/glew.h> 
  #include <GL/wglew.h>
  ```

  to

  ```
  #include "glew.h"
  #include "wglew.h"
  ```
- Created a simple main-file with the following code

  ```
  #define GLEW_STATIC
  #include "glew.h"

  int main() {
      glewInit();
      return 0;
  }
  ```

And with this the compilation will result in tons of warnings
and errors.

- Errors such as:

  ```
  glew.c|2933|undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'|
  glew.c|2934|undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'|
  glew.c|2935|undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'|
  glew.c|2936|undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'|
  ```
- Warnings such as:

  ```
  glew.c|10050|warning: '__wglewReleaseVideoCaptureDeviceNV' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored|
  glew.c|10052|warning: '__wglewBindVideoImageNV' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored|
  glew.c|10053|warning: '__wglewGetVideoDeviceNV' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored|
  glew.c|10054|warning: '__wglewGetVideoInfoNV' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored|
  glew.c|10055|warning: '__wglewReleaseVideoDeviceNV' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored|
  ```

Where did I go wrong?
I would be happy to share more information if necessary!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can eliminate those errors by linking your program with `opengl32` and those warnings by defining `GLEW_STATIC` also in glew.c before the `#include`s.

In any case your program won´t work because you need to have a valid OpenGL context before you can use `glewInit`. You need to create one with glut/glfw/SDL/wglCreateContext/etc.